# How to round Avg() to nearest integer? django

Tags: python, django, numbers, django-views, rounding

I have this in my views.py:

```
user_list = User.objects.select_related().annotate(rating=Avg('userrating__rating')).order_by('-rating')[:5]
```

And I want to round the Avg so I have nice round numbers for a rating.

However, if I use `int(Avg('userrating__rating')))`

it says:

> int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Avg'

if I use `round(Avg('userrating__rating'))` it says:

> TypeError at / a float is required

same for `math.ceil` or `math.floor`

seems like a straight forward thing but I don't know how to do it. Thank you.

Comment: Did my answer help you? If so accept it , please.

Comment: Update: a similar function to the given answers was added in `Django v2.2` under the name [`Round`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.Round)

Answer (score 11):

You can also use [Func() expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions)

```
from django.db.models import Func
class Round(Func):
    function = 'ROUND'
    template='%(function)s(%(expressions)s, 0)'

user_list = User.objects.select_related().annotate(rating=Round(Avg('userrating__rating'))).order_by('-rating')[:5]
```

Answer (score 8):

You can just cast it to an `IntegerField`.

```
from django.db.models import IntegerField

user_list = User.objects.select_related().annotate(
    rating=Avg('userrating__rating', output_field=IntegerField()))
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't round but instead truncates to floor integer.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't try to wrap any conversion function on original orm call, because non of what you tried is valid django api. But you could always convert the number after you got the results:

```
for user in user_list:
    user.rating = int(user.rating)
```